# keep value match in two columns for the same id or 1st row if not in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following sample data set.

```
ID      numb       real
213412  2008       2008
213412  2018       2008
393859  2017       2017
213410  2009       NULL
213410  2020       2013
393859  2021       2021
```

I need to keep rows with the same ID when numb = real else if not (like for id = 213410 ) then I must keep only the first row  (with numb = 2009).
expected output :

```
ID      numb       real
213412  2008       2008
393859  2017       2017
213410  2009       NULL
393859  2021       2021
```

This is my try but it does'nt manage the case when numb != real and only keep first row :

```
df = df.groupby('ID').filter(col("numb") == col("real"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with ranking, so the idea is to rank the rows that have the same ID in the original order, then just keep rank 1 if the numbers don't match.

```py
(df
    .withColumn('mid', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
    .withColumn('rnk', F.rank().over(W.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('mid')))
    .withColumn('keep', F
        .when(F.col('numb') == F.col('real'), True)
        .when(F.col('rnk') == 1, True)
        .otherwise(False)
    )
#     .where(F.col('keep') == True) # uncomment this to filter your desire rows
    .show()
)

# Output
# +------+----+----+-----------+---+-----+
# |    ID|numb|real|        mid|rnk| keep|
# +------+----+----+-----------+---+-----+
# |213412|2008|2008| 8589934592|  1| true|
# |213412|2018|2008|25769803776|  2|false|
# |393859|2017|2017|42949672960|  1| true|
# |393859|2021|2021|94489280512|  2| true|
# |213410|2009|null|60129542144|  1| true|
# |213410|2020|2013|77309411328|  2|false|
# +------+----+----+-----------+---+-----+
```

Comment: @ pltc , seems a good one, but what about the case when the rnk 2 match with real = numb and not rnk = 1 ?

Comment: real = numb is the first condition so it would match first, rnk 2 is second condition. Unless you can give me an example :)

Comment: What 'W' is supposed to mean